# How does one create and load a table into BigQuery with $ value?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dollar-sign

I have a csv with dollar amounts for various products. The column in the csv already contains the "$" in front of the number, and since it's not in "" it can't be a string. How do I load this csv into a BigQuery table?

Comment: The easiest step may be to simply remove these dollar signs from the data in your CSV file before you load it.

Comment: There is not enough information in this post for you to get a good answer. We need to see what you have tried, what has worked, what has not worked, and any errors you get. Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question so you get better answers.

Comment: Load the data into a temporary table, with that value as a string.  Do the data conversion in BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can [load](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) your CSV file directly to BigQuery. If you use the [autodetect schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data) option, the column with numbers starting with "$", might be detected as a number column.

If it gets detected as a string column, then you can follow @GordonLinoff advice and transform it directly in BigQuery.